# Удаление записи flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Сделал такие модели:

```
    class Editor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'editors'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    message_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('messages.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(404))
    tags = db.Column(db.String(100), default=0)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    editor = relationship(Editor, backref="parent", passive_deletes=True)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'text': self.text, 'tags': self.tags, 'date': self.date, 'creator_id': self.creator_id}

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    count_messages = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    api_key = db.Column(db.String(32))
    message = relationship(Message, backref="parent", passive_deletes=True, cascade="all,delete")
    editor = relationship(Editor, backref="parent1", passive_deletes=True, cascade="all,delete")

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.api_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'name': self.name, 'count_messages': self.count_messages}
```

Когда удаляю запись из users видает такую ошибку:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lab_5`.`editors`, CONSTRAINT `editors_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))') [SQL: DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id = %(id)s] [parameters: {'id': 1}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

Удаляю так:

```
db.session.delete(u)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну дык у Вас [определен внешний ключ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) в таблице `lab_5.editors` на таблицу `users`, о чем и говорит сообщение об ошибке:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: **a foreign key constraint fails (lab_5.editors, CONSTRAINT editors_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id))**') [SQL: DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id = %(id)s] [parameters: {'id': 1}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

Определите в этом ключе необходимое поведение при удалении "родительских данных", используя конструкцию `ON DELETE ...`. Иначе перед тем, как удалить пользователя из таблицы `users`, Вам придется вручную удалить все записи, которые на него ссылаются через внешние ключи. Я так понимаю, если пользователь удаляется и `users` - то он уже *никак не может быть редактором* и должен быть удален из `editors`. Вот и добавьте во внешний ключ поведение `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: Не могу понять куда добавить. В Editor кажется уже есть ON DELETE: `user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))`

Comment: Я действительно не знаю питона, мой ответ основывался на знаниях по мускулу.